# Need an explanation for the output of the program.in

Tags: c

While looking at some conceptual questions in C,I came across this question in a book.
What is the output of the following program ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    static char s[25]="The cocaine man";
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    ch=s[++i];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch=s[i++];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch=i++[s];
    printf("%c",ch);
    ch= ++i[s];
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer :

```
 hhe!
```

Can anyone please explain how this output came ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the first assignment

`ch=s[++i];`

increments i(i=1) and assigns `ch` the character at index (i=1) of `s`.

`ch=s[i++];`

assigns `ch` the character at index (i=1) of `s` and then increments i(i=2).

`ch=i++[s];`

assigns `ch` the character at index (i=2) of `s` and then increments i(i=3). Key: `s[i] == i[s]`.

`ch= ++i[s];`

increments the ASCII value at index (i=3) of `s` and assigns it to ch. Key : `[]` has higher precedence than prefix `++`

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this is that in C, the following are equivalent:

```
x[y]
*(x+y)
```

and also that prefix `++` has [lower precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) than `[]`.

A [table of the ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/) will also come in handy.

Comment: let me explain the output correct me where I am wrong,initially i=0 so s[++i] will give me s[1] which is h.After that i=1,s[i++] will give me s[1] which is h and increment i to 2.Then i++[s] will give s[2] which is e and increment i to 3.Am I right ? And how are we getting ! as output for the last ?

Comment: Also notice that ++i[s]==++(i[s]); i.e. Get the value of i[s]==*(i+s) then increment. This explain the "!". Different from i++[s] == *((i++) + s)

Answer (score 0):

- first of all `i=0`, now for `s[++i]`, i=1 and `s[1]` will give h.
- now for `s[i++]`, it will give `s[1]` that is `h` and value of i is 2.
- for `i++[s]`, we must know that `i[s]==s[i]`. Now it will give `s[2]` that is `e` and value of i=3.
- Now for the most important part `++i[s]`, we can think of it as `++(i[s])` because 
  `[ ]` operator has greater precedence than `++`. Since `i[s]` is a char value, `++` operator will work on its ASCII value that is ASCII value of `s[3]` i.e (Space) which is 32 http://www.asciitable.com/ . 32 is incremented by 1 and becomes 33 which is ASCII value of !.